arrows.meta: to improve an arrow
I'm trying to recreate the arrows of this textbook (they are taken from the textbook Halliday-Resnick - Fundamentals of Physics - 10 th edition):
First image:

Second image:

In these previous drawings I see that the thickness between tips are tails are balanced. However, I haven't been able to change the parameters
line width=... and length=...of the triangle, to have the same
view for the two figures with my MWE like the previous images:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
\draw [->] (-0.5,0) -- (3,0) node [below] {$x$};
\draw [->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node [left] {$y$};
\draw [draw=none, fill=orange] (0,0) circle (.5pt);
\draw [arrows = {-Triangle[line width=1pt, fill=white, length=9pt]}, line width=2pt, color=orange] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\draw [arrows = {-Triangle[line width=1.2pt, fill=white, length=9pt]}, line width=1.4pt, color=orange] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output:


by default, arrow tips from arrows.meta are scaled proportionately to the line width, but you are overriding that scaling by setting absolute values. are you trying to make them proportionate to something else? or do you want a different ratio? or ...?

@cfr I would like to have the arrows (tips and tail) like the two images I mentioned at the beginning. I want the same ratio. Thank you for your patience.

Sebastiano, it is not clear to what the tips should be proportional: to the width of the line? Having the same size no matter the width of the line? (Btw, I also am not sure to what you refer when you say "tails", I see only triangular arrow tips in all the images here).

[trans] I write it in Italian and then I will delete the message. I would like the thickness of the line to be visually balanced with the triangle like the first two images. I don't know how to change the parameters to make my vectors like the first two images. Thank you very much

you say the tips are 'in proportion', but in proportion to what?

I have the same problem as cfr. Eitherway, every non-dashes arrow key has three parameters: an absolute dimensions (with units) and two factors. Let's ignore the last factor since it deals with double lines. The length of a tip with the specification length = 3pt 1.5 will set the length to 3pt + 1.5×line width. Basically a fixed base length plus a factor of the line width so that the tip has a minimum length but also scales with the line width. Setting line width = 0pt .5 makes the line width of the tip half as wide as the line width of your path.

The dashed keys (like width') have an absolute part, a length factor and a line width factor. This means width' = 0pt 0.5 will make the tip half as wide as its length. The angle key works a bit different, so does angle'. In theory, this should give you full control over every aspect of a tip's size.

The paths from your external source (seem to) have the same line width, the tips will always have the same size then. In your own code the line widths are different, only absolute dimensions are set, …

@Qrrbrbirlbel I think that the H&R arrows in the first diagram have more or less half the line thickness of the main line, and yes, both arrows have the same thickness. The tip with the dot is different, though, it seems it uses the same thickness. My guess is that the author tuned them manually case per case.

As I stated in my comment above, I think the tips shown there are basically the same. I tried to mimic the two images here; I suspect that the R&H graphic staff tuned the shape of the arrow tips by hand. Anyway, in my comparison these tips are very similar:
\documentclass[border=2.78mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, angles}
\tikzset{rhtip/.tip={Triangle[line width=1pt, fill=white, length=9pt, width=9pt]}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (50:3);
    \coordinate (C) at (15:4);
    \draw pic [draw, angle radius=1cm]{angle=C--A--B};
    \draw [-rhtip, line width=2pt, color=green!70!blue] (A) -- (B);
    \draw [-rhtip, line width=2pt, color=blue!70!gray] (A) -- (C);
    \node [circle, fill=blue!70!gray, inner sep=0.1cm, outer sep=0pt](DOT) at (3,0){};
    \draw [-rhtip, line width=1pt, color=blue!70!gray] (1,0) -- (DOT);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Also, I am quite sure that the fancy superposition of the tails of the arrows at (0,0) has been drawn "by hand":

although you can add a nice touch with line cap=round:


Your work is fine. Wonderful. I will wait a bit for the response of @Qrrbrbirlbel and cfr, which I appreciate so much as users of TeX.SE.
